# Exporting data from Angular to Excel switches columns

Tags: excel, angular, typescript

I'm trying to export data from angular to excel, I'm using JEE for the backend, for now I've no problem and everything works fine. Yet the EXCEL file I get gives me inverted columns.

Here's the component.html

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" sortable="name" (sort)="onSort($event)">Type</th>
      <th>Entité</th>
      <th>Modifié par</th>
      <th>Date de modification</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let x of respTest | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index">
      <td>{{x.Type}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Entite}}</td>
      <td>{{x.ModifiePar}}</td>
      <td>{{x.DateModif}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="exportAsXLSX()">Export</button>
```

and here's the function I use in the component.ts

```
 exportAsXLSX():void {
     this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.respTest, 'suivi');
 }
```

which uses this service  excel.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    //const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getDate() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }

}
```

I want the columns order to be the same as in the table shown in the front.

Comment: For me, Using `XLSX` , the number type columns were appearing in first and then the string type columns. So I used ExcelJS instead of XLSX

Comment: which means that i have to redo all what i did  ?